# Javascript issue with mathematical equations

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, math

Before I begin, I apologize for the possible abundance of code you MAY see in this post. This is the most annoying bug I've ever tried to fix. I've been working for hours, and I still have not found anything.

I have two JavaScript variables, one named `addfood` and one named `clicks`.

The first function below (`addBPS`) takes the numbers from the variables `addfood` and `clicks` and reassigns the sum to the variable `clicks` once again.

The next chunk of the function just runs an animation of the number counting up in a div. It reads the number in the div, and "animates" it up to the new number in the variable `clicks`.

The `if` statement after the function runs the function when the variable `addfood` is greater than zero. It also runs the function `addBPS` every second. Lastly, the `if` statement defines a variable called `first` and sets it to true.

The next function (which is executed when a button is clicked), reassigns the variable `addfood` and adds whatever number `add` had (the variable in the function).

The next line does something similar, and just reassigns the variable `clicks` and subtracts whatever number `cost` had (the variable in the function).

The last if statement, which I believe, is pretty self explanatory. All it does is it runs the function `addBPS` if the variable `addfood` is greater than zero. Then it runs the `setInterval` for the function `addBPS` only if the variable `first` does not equal true. (The variable `first` can also be seen being used on line 19.)

```
var addfood = 5;
var clicks = 123;

function addBPS() {
    clicks = Number(clicks) + Number(addfood);

    // Countup animation
    $({countNum: $('#current').text()}).animate({countNum: Number(clicks)}, {
      duration: 1000,
      easing:'linear',
      step: function() {
        $('#current').text((Math.floor(this.countNum)));
      },
    });
}
if(Number(addfood) > 0) {
    addBPS();
    setInterval(addBPS, 1000);
    var first = true;
}

function upgradeGame(id, level, cost, add, user) {
    addfood = Number(addfood) + Number(add);
    clicks = Number(clicks) - cost;
    if(Number(addfood) > 0) {
        addBPS();
        if(first != true) {
            setInterval(addBPS, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

So now here's where the problem comes in...

The function `addBPS` is ran every second no matter what. It is supposed to continuously add the value of `addfood` to `clicks` every second.

If the value of `addfood` is at least one, the code works perfectly. However, when the value of `addfood` is zero, and THEN if I alter the variable and make it one (by using a button), instead of the code continuously adding the value of `addfood` to `clicks`, it adds it, and each time, SQUARES the value of `addfood`.

**Example:**

*Default:*

addfood = 0;
var clicks = 0;

*Add one to `addfood`:*

addfood = 1;
var clicks (after 1 second) = 1;

*Add two to `addfood`:*

addfood = 2;
var clicks (after 1 second) = 4;

*Add three to `addfood`:*

addfood = 3;
var clicks (after 1 second) = 9;

**What I Expect:**

*Default:*

addfood = 0;
var clicks = 0;

*Add one to `addfood`:*

addfood = 1;
var clicks (after 1 second) = 1;

*Add two to `addfood`:*

addfood = 2;
var clicks (after 1 second) = 2;

*Add three to `addfood`:*

addfood = 3;
var clicks (after 1 second) = 3;

However, like I said, if the initial value of `addfood` is one, then the code works fine. When it is zero, and then I change the value of `addfood` by using a button, the expected value is squared. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for easing debug process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time upgradeGame() is called, a new Interval will be created. So after the first click, it will be called only once. After the second click it will be called twice, etc. To solve this you need to include

```
first=true;
```

So:

```
function upgradeGame(id, level, cost, add, user) {
addfood = Number(addfood) + Number(add);
clicks = Number(clicks) - cost;
if(Number(addfood) > 0) {
    addBPS();
    if(first != true) {
        setInterval(addBPS, 1000);
        first=true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This just made my day. After so many hours, such a simple solution! All I can say is thank you.